# Different Json Links For Different Tab Menu in Android

Tags: android

**class TabAdapter**

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public TabAdapter( FragmentManager fm )
    {
        super( fm );
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem( int position )
    {
        switch ( position )
        {
            case 0 :
                return new TabStarterFragment();
            case 1 :
                return new TabMainCourseFragment();
            case 2 :
                return new TabDessertFragment();
            case 3 :
                return new TabChineseFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return int_items;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle( int position )
    {
        switch ( position )
        {
            case 0 :
                return "Starter";
            case 1 :
                return "MainCourtse";
            case 2 :
                return "Dessert";
            case 3 :
                return "Chinese";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

`class TabAdapter` image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zva7e.png)

**interface DishItemApi**

```
public interface DishItemAPI
{
    /* @GET("/item.php?sid=1")
    void getDishItems(Callback<String> dishitems);

    @GET("/item.php?sid=2")   // Breakfast Snadwitch
    void getDishItems(Callback<String> dishitems);

    /* @GET("/item.php?sid=3")
    void getDishItems(Callback<String> dishitems);

    /* @GET("/item.php?sid=4")
    void getDishItems(Callback<String> dishitems);

    @GET("/item.php?sid=5")
    void getDishItems(Callback<String> dishitems);*/
```

`DishItemAPI` image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdcDz.png).

I wanted to change the different json links as I change the tab menu. For a particular tab I want to parse a particular json link in android application by using Retrofit. Please reply me if anyone have an example for it.

Comment: For future reference, it is generally preferred that you copy code segments into your Questions as text and format it as a Code Segment by highlighting the text and clicking on the `{}` button above the text entry area.  For code segments that wholly occupy their line(s) (such as with your code segments above), you may also format them by indenting each line by four spaces.  For in-line code (such as in the image link lines above), you may also place`\``'s either side of the text.

Comment: Links to images should not be exclusively relied upon, partly because they break over time and partly because being able to copy and manipulate a segment of code makes it much easier to debug and provide a solution with.  You can still include links to the images if you wish, as has been done above.  If you feel that an image contains information that can not be readily represented as text, such as with a diagram, you can make it appear in the body of the question by changing `[enter image description here][1]` to `![][1]`.  Any questions you have are welcome.